# How to produce waterfall plot using shapely from loaded xgboost model

Tags: python, xgboost, shap

I have this xgboost model that I created as a test to save as JSON in R. After I built the model in R, I saved it using `xgb.save(model, fname='xgboost_classifer_model.json')`.

I then used `xgboost` package in python to load the model like the following:

```
import xgboost
bst = xgboost.Booster()
bst.load_model('./model/xgboost_classifier_model.json')
input_data = np.array([1,1,1,1],dtype=np.float16).reshape(1,-1)
```

I then used `shap` package to create explainer.

```
import shap

explainer = shap.Explainer(bst)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(input_data)
shap_values[0]
```

Finally, I used the `sap_values` to plot

```
shap.waterfall_plot(shap_values)
plt.title("SHAP Values Waterfall Plot")
plt.xlabel("SHAP Value")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I'm getting `The waterfall plot requires an` Explanation`object as the`shap_values `argument.` error.

What am I doing wrong and not understanding here?

**Model**
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6vn2shyvz1hn7b4majqzh/xgboost_classifier_model.json?rlkey=sha8gb61eox5mqcuudf3t2v5p&dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `waterfall_legacy` to plot waterfall plots. Here's your corrected code:

```
import shap

explainer = shap.Explainer(xgb, X_train)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

plt.title("SHAP Values Waterfall Plot")
plt.xlabel("SHAP Value")
plt.tight_layout()
shap.plots._waterfall.waterfall_legacy(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0], feature_names=X_train.columns)
```

Output:

[image: waterfall plot]

##### If you want to see model interpretation on test data or unseen data:

Just make sure your unseen data format is consistent with your model train-data format.

```
import shap

explainer = shap.Explainer(xgb, X_test)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

plt.title("SHAP Values Waterfall Plot")
plt.xlabel("SHAP Value")
plt.tight_layout()
shap.plots._waterfall.waterfall_legacy(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0], feature_names=X_test.columns)
```

Output:
[image]

The plots are generated using one of my own data and models.

Comment: So, is it not possible to create the waterfall or any explanation plot using the new data like ‘input_data’ in my case? I had tried the way you showed from examples on the internet and they work. I wanted to show the plot for the new incoming data for predictions. Is that not possible? Am I misunderstanding SHAP?

Comment: No it's definitely possible. I added how you can do it with unseen data too. Just make sure your test data or unseen data format is consistent with train data too. It's similar to how you would infer from your model, you would have to provide unseen data cosistently formatted according to you model train data